# Can't convert value of class org.json.JSONObject to class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer/ JsonSerializer

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

How looks my configurations:

```
Map<String, Object> props = kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties();

props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
```

Which serializer should i use for JSONObject?

Should i send by kafkaTemplate JsonObject to it would be better to send String? (jsonObject.toString());

Comment: if you deserialize data from this configuration too, you have to configure the deserializer too. org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

Comment: @GavinSmith If you have a custom model, better write a serializer for that

Comment: @JavaTechnical at first i had model, which i mapped by jackson and send to kafka in string format, but current goal is to use JSONObject

Comment: could you put your data passing code into kafka template?

Comment: @GavinSmith Then, you can write a `Serializer<JSONObject>`

Comment: @JavaTechnical so it is much faster to use just String? I mean we have DTO ```User```, we map it to json by Jackson and send to kafka. With json objectc we have Mapping ```User``` to JsonObject and then Serializing and Deserializing it

Comment: @GavinSmith See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is always recommended to use a *specific* serializers for Kafka producer instead of using `StringSerializer`. The reason is that, string is very generic and it can be either a vaild or invalid JSON string.

If you use `StringSerializer`, the `KafkaProducer` serializer does not complain if the given string is a valid JSON or not.

So, in future if some developer tries to send a malformed JSON string, it can affect the consumer. Also, the serializer that you would write can be reusable for similar use-cases.

So, better write a new serializer which validates the JSON string (or) write `JSONObjectSerializer` or even a serializer for your custom POJO class (if you have any).

```java
public class JSONObjectSerializer implements Serializer<JSONObject> {
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, JSONObject data) {
       return data.toString().getBytes(); // or whatever is appropriate.
    }
}
```

You anyway have to convert it to JSON, the point is that instead of doing in your main logic (KafkaProducer), you write that in a `Serializer`

In case you want to convert any object to JSON.

```java
private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
   return objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(data);
}
```